# JQuery doesn't get the changes that angularjs does

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've got this set with AngularJS

```
<span data-end-time="{{ productAuctionEnd | date:'yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss' }},000" class="detail-rest-time js-time-left"></span>
```

and when I use this jquery

```
$(".js-time-left").each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).data("end-time"));
}
```

the first log prints this to screen:

```
<span data-end-time="2016,06,12,15,03,59,000" class="detail-rest-time js-time-left"></span>
```

the second log prints this:

```
,000
```

can anyone please help me out

Comment: Better not to use jQuery in Angular. Use AngularJS **magic**

Comment: Probably you're trying to read values before Angular has updated. ^^^

Comment: @Tushar is there a way to know when the changes are made? eg. onChange(productAuctionEnd).dothis(function(){...})

Comment: @user2896551, yes there is.  Add a watch to your controller for productAuctionEnd.

Comment: @user2896551, I tried that, still get the same outcome :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

Just call the jQuery logic after angular and it will work.Sometimes the two don't play nice together:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module("app", []);
    myApp.controller('controller', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.productAuctionEnd = new Date();

    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $(".js-time-left").each(function () {
            console.log($(this));
            console.log($(this).data("end-time"));
        });
    });

</script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <span data-end-time="{{ productAuctionEnd | date:'yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss' }},000" class="detail-rest-time js-time-left"></span>
</div>
```

**Output in Google Chrome console:**

[image: Writing to Chrome console from jQuery]

Comment: This is definitely not a solid solution and there is no mention of using proper angular methodology

Comment: No need to be rude or offensive